# Getting a random value from a JavaScript array (click button)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
let text = ["hello", "world", "where", "list", "tes", "new"];
const btn = document.querySelector(".button");

btn.addEventListener("click", random);
const randomText = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);

function random() {
  const pText = document.querySelector(".p-text");
  const textRandom = (pText.innerHTML = `${text[randomText]}`);
}
```

hy guys, can you help me.?
how do I still get random results when I click the button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Move randomText inside of the random function so it's called (and randomized) every time - right now it's set once so each call to `random()` will return the same value. But additionally, please read over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with relevant HTML too (in case your error is there), and what your expected results are. What have you tried to debug your code so far?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not super clear what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to change the text on some paragraph element every time someone clicks a button? Not that right now your randomText index is a constant! Change that to a function and you should be go to go.

Comment: Try moving `const randomText = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);` to your function `random()`.

Answer (score 1):

call the `randomText` inside the random function. because it should run every time you click the button

```
function random() {
  const randomText = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);// here
  const pText = document.querySelector(".p-text");
  const textRandom = (pText.innerHTML = `${text[randomText]}`);
}
```

Comment: it works.. Thak you so much broo, God bless you :D

Answer (score 1):

```
function random() {
  const pText = document.querySelector(".p-text");
  // move your randomText into function, so that it will have new value when the function is called.
  const randomText = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);
  const textRandom = (pText.innerHTML = `${text[randomText]}`);
}
```

Comment: it works.. Thak you so much for comment broo, God bless you :D